# Php - How to sum hours?

Tags: php

I have to hours, `11:00:00` and `06:30:00` and I want to sum this 2 values, `17:30:00`.

I try to do that with `carbon` but it returns me a wrong value!

```
$startTime1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '11:00:00');
$startTime2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '06:30:00');

$total_in_seconds = $startTime1->timestamp + $startTime2->timestamp;
$totalInterventions = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($total_in_seconds)->format('h:i:s');
```

But it returns me `05:30`, the difference between this 2 hours.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
$startTime1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '11:00:00');
$startTime2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '06:30:00');

$total_in_seconds = $startTime1->timestamp + $startTime2->timestamp;
$totalInterventions = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($total_in_seconds)-
```

`>format('h:i:s');` <--- This would likely cause you an issue.

Try instead

```
>format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will do trick for you.

```
        $time = new Carbon($startTime1);
        $startTime2=new Carbon($startTime2);
        $time->diffForHumans($startTime2);
```